# Регулярное выражение в Notepad?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

> [lang=en]Home[/lang]
>
> [lang=en]Любой текст[/lang]

Как мне убрать с файла этот текст. Все что между lang может быть любое

Comment: что именно убрать? Сам уже пытался найти решение (тут наверняка есть не один вопрос с похожей задачей)

Comment: [lang=en]Любой текст[/lang]. Все вхождения. Где любой текст. Может быть что угодно

Comment: с чем проблема-то? справку по регуляркам в руки и вперед. Тут все очень просто.

Comment: Не получилось у меня

Comment: Notepad или Notepad++? Это очень сильно разные вещи, в Notepad регулярных выражений вообще нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам нужно регулярное выражение, то подойдёт это: `(\[lang=en\])(.*)(\[\/lang\])`.

Comment: Работает
а как сделать, чтоб оставалось только допустим Выйти, но заместо выйти может быть любой текст?
[lang=ru]Выйти[/lang][lang=en]Go out[/lang]

Comment: Вы хотите удалить [lang=en] и [/lang], а оставить только текст внутри?

Comment: я хочу удалить все теги lang, и оставить русский текст. но я думаю нельзя так. хотя может я не прав

Comment: Если вы используете Notepad++, то там в find what: вставляет регулярное выражение, которое выше, а в replace with: $2